# How to debug mockito mocks/stubs/matchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

During normal test development using mockito, I (and many others for sure) run into many situations where our when(service.doSomething(paramMatcher, paramMatcher2, ...).thenReturn(...) drives me crazy. So many combinations that are possible between lists, vargars, null values, etc. it is often hours spent just trying to get the formula right and even then I give up and just use any() with thenAnswer(manual matching).

How can I debug the parameter matching mechanism of mockito? For added difficulty, I run my tests using Mockito runner which means that I use annotation to initialize and automatically inject my mocked services.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can enable verbose logging on your Mocked objects:

```java
    import org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
    import org.mockito.Mockito.withSettings;

    List mockWithLogger = mock(List.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
```

This should give you more information to understand the interactions.

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#verboseLogging()

Comment: Saw this but how can I integrate this with @Mock way of creating my mocks?

Comment: @Pierre Using annotation-driven declarations won't work. You need to switch to in-line instantiation.